# How integrate two ModelForms to render one form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I created two classes: Client (attributes: name and sex) and Account (attributes: customer[fk], the payment status). I show the form from templates; When I click the link "Add Customer" it opens the form of creation, from what has in models.py, other words can only create a client to "name and sex," but not I can integrate in the same form payment situation.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Cliente(models.Model):
    SEXO = (
        ('M', 'Masculino'),
        ('F','Feminino'),
    )

    nome = models.CharField("Nome do cliente", max_length=255)
    sexo = models.CharField("Sexo", max_length=1, choices=SEXO)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nome

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cliente'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Clientes'

class Conta(models.Model):
    STATUS_CONTA = (
            ('A', 'A Pagar'),
            ('P', 'Pago'),
        )

    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, related_name='conta')
    situacao = models.CharField("Situação", max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CONTA)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Conta'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Contas'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.cliente.nome
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms.models import ModelForm
from cadastro.models import Cliente, Conta

__author__ = 'Admin'

class ClienteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cliente
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<a href='/adicionar_cliente/'>Adicionar cliente</a>
    {% for cliente in clientes %}
        {% for conta in cliente.conta.all %}
            <p>Nome: {{cliente.nome}}</p>
            <p>Sexo: {{cliente.get_sexo_display}} </p>
            <p>Situação do pedido: {{conta.get_situacao_display}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
            <p><a href='/excluir/{{cliente.id}}/'>Excluir?</a></p>
            <p><a href='/editar/{{cliente.id}}/'>Editar</a></p>
            <hr>
    {% empty %}
            <h3>Não existe nenhum cliente.</h3>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

**form.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action='/{{action}}/' method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{form}}
        </table>
        <input type='submit' value='Adicionar' />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. 27 questions. Looks like all of them with answers, but only 2 accepted. If you can't reward the people who take time from their busy lives to help you, you don't deserve help.

Comment: I don't know how does it work the scoring system, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two forms to accomplish this task.

### forms.py

```
...
class ClienteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cliente
class ContaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Conta
        exclude = ("cliente") #exclude the cliente field from showing up in the form rendering.
```

### form.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form action='/{{ action }}/' method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }} <!-- added as table which was missing from original post. -->
        {{ form2.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type='submit' value='Adicionar' />
</form>
</body>
```

### views.py

```
...
def form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClienteForm(request.POST)
        form2 = ContaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            client = form.save()
            conta = form2.save(commit=False)
            conta.cliente = client
            contra.save()
    else:
        form = ClienteForm()
        form2 = ContaForm()
       return render_to_response('form.html', locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Now, nothing is shown. Only the two links to exclude and edit.